# Disabling 3-Click Edit of a JTree node but keeping keyoard keys to edit for saving the old name of the node prior to edit

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I want to be able to edit the nodename with *F2* and *ENTER* keys only, not with mouse. I added these 2 lines and they are working:

```
jTree1.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "startEditing");
jTree1.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F2, 0), "startEditing");
```

But how do I disable editing from mouse? Are there any methods like: `jTree1.setToggleClickCount(2);`

The reason I want to do this is that I want to keep the old name of the node, so I'll create a keylistener to listen for F2 and ENTER and keep the names that way. Does that make sense? Any thoughts?

Comment: an aside: *don't* use KeyListeners, *do* use keybindings instead

Answer (score 2):

You can disable editing with mouse with help of `TreeCellEditor`, try next code:

```
DefaultTreeCellEditor editor = new DefaultTreeCellEditor(t, (DefaultTreeCellRenderer) t.getCellRenderer()){
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject event) {
        if(event instanceof MouseEvent){
            return false;
        }
        return super.isCellEditable(event);
    }
};
```

that editor prevents editing with `MouseEvent`.

Set that editor to your `JTree` with next line: `tree.setCellEditor(editor);`

where `tree` is your `JTree`.

Comment: you can't start TreeCellEditor, to consume() mouse events invoked (2-3 mouse clicks, 3mouse clicks if 1st is about focus, node selected )

Comment: I couldn't get this to working, what is "t" at the first line?

Comment: Yes, it is now working but it is long way from what I need. I tried keybindings while blocking mouse but it is not working. Can you perhaps suggest any other way? I'm just trying to store the previous name of a node if a node gets edited. I used a **MyTreeModelListener** but it only gives me the node after the name (UserObject) changes...